# String to DateTime dd/mm/yy error

Tags: c#, datetime

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Timesheets\2011", "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)){             
  Paycheck p = new Paycheck(DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("_" + 1), 6), "dd/mm/yy", null), file);
  _Paychecks.Add(p);
}
```

I am trying to get a `DateTime` from a filename that my program will be scanning through. The `DateTime` is formatted as dd/mm/yy. Every time I get to this line of code:

`Paycheck p = new Paycheck(DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("_" + 1), 6), "dd/mm/yy", null), file);`

The program breaks to the application without doing anything. It will not give me an error message and any information as to what is going on. I'm sure I've written this in some sort of confusing manner so let me know what you need clarification on.

Here is an example of one of the file names incase that helps;

Weekly Time & Expense Sheet_AT_073111

Comment: break this line apart into two - create your `DateTime` instance on the first line..and look at it with the debugger

Comment: so like this?
`DateTime test = DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("_" + 1), 8), "dd/MM/yy", null);

Paycheck p = new Paycheck(test, file);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use capital `MM` to represent `Month` instead of small `mm`

from your sample Date string `07312011` it looks like

first two digits - `07` =>  `Month`
next two digits - `31` => `Date`
next four digits - `2011` => `Year`

hence your format should be `MMddyyyy`

**EDIT:**  you need to add 1 after closing the `LastIndexOf()` function

Try This:

```
Paycheck p = new Paycheck(DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(
                   file.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, 6), "MMddyyyy", null), file);
```

Comment: Still just breaks to the application without executing the code

Comment: @teepee: check my edited answer, your format should be `MMddyyyy`

Comment: okay I just realized that some files are MMddyy and others are ddMMyy, I manually changed the one I pasted onto this post to 0731"20"11 as a test to try to fix my problem and accidentally forgot to fix it before I posted it. However the first file the program tries to scan is formatted as MMddyy and it is still breaking without any errors

Comment: to try and simplify this know that the first file my program is scanning, is formatted as MMddyy "073111" but the program is still breaking when it runs that code formatted as;

`Paycheck p = new Paycheck(DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("_" + 1), 6), "MMddyy", null), file);`

Comment: @teepee: you need to add 1 after closing the lastindexof function , try this `Paycheck p = new Paycheck(DateTime.ParseExact(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, 6), "MMddyyyy", null), file);` check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

while converting string to DateTime,
         use

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(//your string which is converted to DateTime//).
```